# How to place a menu item in a fixed position on top of a carousel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, carousel

I am using wt-rotator carousel plugin with bootstrap. I have to place a menu on top of the carousel on the top left, in a fixed position. The menu should stay there even as the images fade in and fade out. Is there a way to do it using  CSS?

Edit: added the code below.
So far just this code below. it is a bootstrap jumbotron, which has a wt-rotator carousel inside. On top of this carousel, I have to put a menu.

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">      
        <div id="banner-container">

            <div class="wt-rotator">
                <div class="c-panel">               
                    <div class="thumbnails">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="images/image1.jpg"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="images/image2.jpg"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="images/image3.jpg"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="images/image4.jpg"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div class="prev-btn"></div>
                        <div class="play-btn"></div>
                        <div class="next-btn"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you add code snippet with what you've tried so far?

Comment: An example would definitely help us understand your question...As it sits right now, it sounds like all you need to do is add a separate div and in your css, set that div to `position: fixed;`.  That way, your div (or in this case, your menu) would be fixed and outside of your carousel plugin.

Comment: posted the html, I actually don't have any CSS because I just used the default CSS classes from bootstrap and wt-rotator

Answer (score 0):

You can use a outside div with position absolute and z-index superior to the slider, and put that div on front of the slider.

Comment: okay, that worked, thank you. It is messed up on the phone though, since I put the position absolute :( on the computer it looks nice. Is there any trick to make it work on the phone?

Comment: Can you show the example so i can test?

You need to use the position on %, instead of px. Maybe that work